# Find the category which has 3 or more than 3 products data by using the linq and lambda query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to find the category id or category name which has 3 or more products.

The List is in a class Category but I have to write out the result in main.

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts( )
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>( );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Milk",           Price = 90,  CategoryID = 4, ID = 1 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Cheese",         Price = 130, CategoryID = 4, ID = 2 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Butter",         Price = 110, CategoryID = 4, ID = 3 } );

    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Apple juice",    Price = 230, CategoryID = 1, ID = 4 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Grape juice",    Price = 240, CategoryID = 1, ID = 5 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Beetroot juice", Price = 300, CategoryID = 1, ID = 6 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Carrot juice",   Price = 190, CategoryID = 1, ID = 7 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Ginger ale",     Price = 990, CategoryID = 1, ID = 8 } );

    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Oregano",        Price = 500, CategoryID = 2, ID = 9 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Salt",           Price = 550, CategoryID = 2, ID = 10 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Pepper",         Price = 490, CategoryID = 2, ID = 11 } );

    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Carrots",        Price = 300, CategoryID = 3, ID = 12 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Spinach",        Price = 250, CategoryID = 3, ID = 13 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Onion",          Price = 200, CategoryID = 3, ID = 14 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Garlic",         Price = 150, CategoryID = 3, ID = 15 } );
    products.Add( new Product { Name = "Tomatoes",       Price = 100, CategoryID = 3, ID = 16 } );

    return products;
}
```

Comment: Please when copy-paste assignments don't add random text like "new here" and "searched a lot". Your teacher likely put some effort to make assignment clear and readable - so why make it hard to read by adding random text? Now to make it good SO question you need to show what you've tried (I've removed "searched a lot" from your post as it was not supported by any code that may be related to the task).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var products = GetProducts();
IEnumerable<int> categoriesWithThreeOrMoreProducts =
            from p in products
            group p by p.CategoryID into grps
            where grps.Count() >= 3
            select grps.Key;
```

You take your list of products, group the products by category (so `grps` becomes a mapping, mapping each category id to the products in that category), select the groups which contain three or more elements, then return the key (category id) of those groups.

Or, a little less LINQ-ish:

```
IEnumerable<int> categoriesWithThreeOrMoreProducts =
                   products.ToLookup(p => p.CategoryID)
                           .Where(g => g.Count() >= 3)
                           .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Hey, I liked your answer with ToLookup - why did you changed your answer? I mean is there any pitfalls with it?

Comment: Using ToLookup is alright and may be a little more readable, I just wanted to give the OP the most LINQ-ish answer. I've put it back in.

Comment: Thanks, found out smth new today, already didn't wasted a day:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able doing this with follows:

```
    var p1 = GetProducts();  

    var res =p1
            .GroupBy(p => p.CategoryID)
            .Where(g => g.Count() >= 3)
            .SelectMany(g => g.CategoryName);
```

If you are needed names of products then you need make like this, but if only CategoryID -> Select(g => g.Key)